# Searching a value using for-loop and

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop, unique

The question is this:

Given a non-empty array of integers, every element appears twice except for one. Find that single one.

Input: [4,1,2,1,2]
Output: 4

my code is:

```
public static int singleNumber(int[] nums) {
     int answer = 0;
        for (int i =0; i<nums.length-1; i++) {
            for(int j = i+1; j<nums.length; j++) {
                if(nums[i] != nums[j]) {
                 answer = nums[i];      //this should be where I am wrong.
                }
            }
        }
        return answer;
    }
```

I know that the output was 4 and then now it will be changed to 1.
I'm trying to figure out how not to change the found value once found.

Comment: I'd use a HashBag (or implement such a bag using a Map) and then return the set of all objects which have a count of one.

Comment: Are there any limitations on the input numbers? (example: they are between 1-10 etc)

Comment: I have not learned Hash yet.. so this is the way I'm doing right now.
And there is no limit on input numbers (sorry about not being specific for it earlier)

Comment: is this an algorithm problem or an implementation problem?

Answer (score 8):

The logic is wrong - your inner loop finds every number that isn't the only number in the array.

I'd maintain a `Set` to track the numbers I've encountered. The first time you encounter a number, you add it to the `Set`. The second time you encounter it, you remove it from the `Set`. Once you're done going over the array, you'd have a `Set` with a single element, which is your answer:

```
public static int singleNumber(int[] nums) {
    Set<Integer> unique = new HashSet<>();
    for (int num : nums) {
        // add returns true if num is indeed new to unique
        if (!unique.add(num)) {
            unique.remove(num);
        }
    }

    return unique.iterator().next();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For this problem, i would to bitwise XOR of the numbers. The numbers that are equal will cancel one another and only single integer will be the final value.

```
public static int singleNumber(int[] nums) {
     int answer = 0;
        for (int i =0; i<nums.length; i++) {
           answer = answer ^ nums[i];
        }
        return answer;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

below changes to your method will give you the expected answer

```
public static int singleNumber(int[] nums) {

    int temp = 0;
    int answer = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        boolean flag = true;
        temp = nums[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < nums.length; j++) {
            if (temp == nums[j]) {
                if (i != j) {// if a match found then the loop will terminate
                    flag = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
        if (flag == true) {
            answer = temp;
        }
    }
    return answer;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution using `Collectors.groupingBy` from Java 8 :

```
public static int singleNumber(int[] nums) {
    return Arrays.stream(nums).boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(a -> a, Collectors.counting()))
            .entrySet().stream().filter(e -> e.getValue() == 1).findFirst().get().getKey();
}
```

the idea is :

- group by number of occurence
- then find the one which is repeated just one time

---

Note I assume that your array contain at least one element, else you can check the length before you search then throw an exception like this :

```
public static int singleNumber(int[] nums) throws IllegalArgumentException{
    if(nums.length == 0){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("empty array");
    }
    return Arrays.stream(nums).boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(a -> a, Collectors.counting()))
            .entrySet().stream().filter(e -> e.getValue() == 1).findFirst().get().getKey();
}
```

---

More deeper, If you want to avoid the situation where there are multiple number repeated just one time you can use :

```
public static int singleNumber(int[] nums) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    if (nums.length == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("empty array");
    }
    Map<Integer, Long> grouping = Arrays.stream(nums).boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(a -> a, Collectors.counting()));
    if (grouping.values().stream().filter(c -> c == 1).count() > 1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("more than one element is repeated one time");
    }

    return grouping.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(e -> e.getValue() == 1).findFirst().get().getKey();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution which uses ArrayList.indexOf and ArrayList.lastIndexOf. If they are same, you have your answer.

```
public static int singleNumber(int[] nums) {
    int answer = 0;
    //ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(nums));
    ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
    for (int i =0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        al.add(nums[i]);
    }

    for (int i =0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        int test = nums[i];
        if(al.indexOf(test) == al.lastIndexOf(test)){
            answer = nums[i];
        }
    }
    return answer;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    int[] nums = new int[] {4,2,1,2,1};
         int answer = 0;
            for (int i =0; i<nums.length-1; i++) {
                int times = 0;
                int target = nums[i];
                for(int j : nums) {
                    if(j == target) {
                        times++;
                        if(times == 2) {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(times == 1) {
                    answer = target;
                    break;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(answer);
```

you have to go into every number and count how meny are in the array if there is only 1 you instantly stop the loop end set the answer

Comment: Instead of checking if `times==1`, why not just break as soon as `times` becomes 2, then you can set `answer = target` if it managed to reach the end without exiting